# How set charset encoding of pytest mock response?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I learned about the encoding of python string.

In python, strings are all same though there were encoded with different types.

```py
error_msg = 'text'
response_text = error_msg.encode().decode('ISO-8859-1')
response_target1 = error_msg.encode().decode('cp949')
response_target2 = error_msg.encode().decode('utf-8')
response_target3 = error_msg.encode().decode('euc-kr')
print(response_text == response_target1)  # True
print(response_text == response_target2)  # True
print(response_text == response_target3)  # True
```

But when I got a text from the response, python gives `False` if the encoding is different between the response and my string variable though It has the same value. I fixed my code to compare string after decoding to the same type.

So I want to make pytest function with mocking, to test my decoding function.

```py
mock_request.return_value = mock.Mock(
            status_code='200',
            text='text',
            headers={'content-type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'}
)
assert mock_request.return_value != 'text'  # expected True but gives False
```

I expected `mock_request.return_value.text != 'text'` gives me `True` because encoding types are different from each other, but It gives me `False`.

I don't know how to set charset when using pytest mock instance.

Is there any way to set charset encoding type when using pytest mock? Please help me.

---

```py
import requests
from unittest import mock


def test():
    response = mock.Mock()
    response.headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'}
    response.text = 'text'
    requests.post.return_value = response
    # the rest of your test code here
    assert requests.post.return_value.text in ['text']
```

And also this code gives me `True` though charsets are different each other.

Comment: I think you are mixing strings with bytes here - strings (`str`) are always unicode, and have no encoding. If you want to write a string into a byte array (or read it from a byte array), you need an encoding, but if you decode a pure ASCII byte array with different encodings, it will most likely create the same string, as most encodings are a subset of ASCII. So to test encodings, you need a string that is not ASCII. Also, your assert makes no sense - you assign a Mock to `return_value` and afterwards compare it to a string. I guess you are not showing the real code here.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I created `mock.Mock()` object for testing it in pytest because I can't request to real site. Do I don't need to encode to same encoding type when compare response.text and string variable if there same ascii value?

Comment: As I wrote, ASCII values are encoded the same in most encodings, certainly in the default encoding. Also note that setting arbitrary arguments to the mock doesn't do anything - it just constructs a mock.